# Find children of type canvas in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Here is a code snippet of the HTML that I have:

I have row

```
<tr class ="chart_row">
<td>
<span><canvas style="display: inline-block; width: 70px; height: 20px; vertical-align: top;" width="70" height="20"></canvas>
</td>
</tr>
```

There could be multiple td's with elements of type canvas. I want to apply the css style `{cursor:pointer}` programatically to all canvas elements within a row of class chart_row using jquery.

I tried something like this:

```
$('.chart_row canvas')each(function() 
    { 
             $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer'); 
    }); 
 });
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Well you're missing the `.` before `each`

Comment: You are missing a dot: `$('.chart_row canvas')` **`.`** `each(function()...`. A look at the error console would have told you that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing a period before `.each()` which a glance at your javascript error console or debug console would have shown you.  But, that isn't even the simplest way to do this.  You should be using this:

```
$(".chart_row canvas").css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

You don't have to use `.each()` at all as you can just call jQuery methods directly on the jQuery object and those methods will operate on every element in the jQuery object (they use `.each()` internally).

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2HnNj/